# Conversion from C to C++ avoiding <strsafe.h>

Tags: c++, c

Recently I read a post here in S.O. which claimed to have the solution for removing a file after its execution, providing some code to do so.

Then I figured out that it was written in C and used a library called strsafe.h, which I have read in some other forums that is a Visual library and it doesn't work on C++.

Is there a working solution for using this code in C++?  Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define SELF_REMOVE_STRING  TEXT("cmd.exe /C ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > Nul & Del \"%s\"")

void DelMe()
{
    TCHAR szModuleName[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szCmd[2 * MAX_PATH];
    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};

    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szModuleName, MAX_PATH);

    StringCbPrintf(szCmd, 2 * MAX_PATH, SELF_REMOVE_STRING, szModuleName);

    CreateProcess(NULL, szCmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}

void main()
{
    /* Do what you need */

    /* Call this function at the very end of your program to delete itself */
    DelMe();
}
```

Comment: This code works fine in C++, as long as you're on Windows. But since you didn't mention doing it without `<Windows.h>`, I assume that's not a problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes I know it's just for Windows but I can't compile it due to strsafe.h

Comment: This (or rather, "such") code *does not work fine* on systems that *demand page* an executable from the binary file on disk. Such systems need to lock the file when a process is being executed from there because it needs to stay accessible and its integrity secured for later page-ins.

Comment: @J.Doe - In case you get it past the "strsafe.h" stage, you will run into many more problems - Most of the used system calls are simply not there in this form on non-windows OSs.

Comment: @J.Doe: What is your error? It works fine for me.

Comment: The above call to `StringCbPrintf` is actually wrong. The second parameter is supposed to be the destination buffer size in bytes, not TCHARs, so the second parameter should be `2 * MAX_PATH * sizeof(TCHAR)` in this case, or just `sizeof(szCmd)` since `szCmd` is an array.

Comment: @tofro I think the intention of the above code is that the program _should_ have already exited by the time the spawned process attempts to delete its .exe file. Of course, there are several reasons why that attempt might fail.

Comment: What does "%s\" really do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only function from `<strsafe.h>` here is `StringCbPrintf` which you can replace with `wsprintf`

```
//StringCbPrintf(szCmd, 2 * MAX_PATH, SELF_REMOVE_STRING, szModuleName);
wsprintf(szCmd, SELF_REMOVE_STRING, szModuleName);
```

However, you won't be able to port it to other platforms so easily, because of Windows native functions used.

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate in TEXT() other cmd commands such as rename a file name?

Comment: @J.Doe SELF_REMOVE_STRING is used as format string, so if you want to add another parameters use `%s` or other format specifiers in there, or add additional commands, etc.

Comment: I tried #define SELF_REMOVE_STRING  TEXT("cmd.exe /C Del \"%s\" & ren %cd%\file1.txt newname.txt") and it doesn't work. The file is removed (first command run succesfully) but it seems like the second command is never run.

Comment: @J.Doe this is a format string, `%` is a special symbol, you need to escape it `#define SELF_REMOVE_STRING TEXT("cmd.exe /C Del \"%s\" & ren %%cd%%\file1.txt newname.txt")`

Comment: Still not working. I get the same result as before. I don't know what's wrong

Comment: @J.Doe there might be a problem with `%cd%` variable, it points to current dir, however, current dir might not be the one you think it is. Try outputting in to some file in known location and see what it really is

Comment: Finally it worked!! What I've done is to remove %%cd%%\ and it works. But it's only fine if the file that you want to rename is in the same directory as the executable one.